# get ASPX radiobutton text or value from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

ASPX radiobuttons are inside a datalist template

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  
        GroupName="rdb" 
        Text='<%#  Eval("type1") %>'  
        onclick="Getr1(this)"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function getr1(val){
    alert(val)
}
```

if I use this function in any html control, it will return a value but it is not working in the aspx radiobuttons. I used this code:  `onchange="GetQty(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"` to get the selected index from an aspx dropdownlist and it works just fine, maybe someone can help me to figure out the correct syntax for aspx rb. I already tried `onclick="Getr1(this.options[this.checked].value)"`,   THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Have you tried OnClientClick?

Comment: changing the questions title to solved is not the way here. please mark as answer, the one helped you solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, just need a little change.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  
    CliientIDMode="Static" GroupName="rdb" 
    Text='<%#  Eval("type1") %>' />
```

and

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-size: x-small"
    Text='<%# Eval("type1") %>'></asp:Label>
```

jQuery for getting **RadioButton Text**:

```
$("#RadioButton1").click(function{
    alert( $(this).siblings('label').text());
});
```

jQuery for getting **asp:Label Text** next to the RadioButton:

```
$("#RadioButton1").click(function{
    alert( $(this).siblings('span').text());
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your responses but I still can't get the value

Comment: ok here is the updated code of javascript function GetR1(obj) {
        
    
        if (obj.checked = true) {      
           
           alert(obj.value);  which returns the id:RadioButton)                                                          here is the radiobutton: <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="rdb" Text='<%# Eval("type1") %>' onclick="GetR1(this)" /> and its label:
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-size: x-small" Text='<%# Eval("type1") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: Now I know that the function is working but how can I get the text of the radio or label. if I try alert(obj.text) returns identified. I just need to modified the js but I'm clueless at this point. Thank you for taking your time to help me. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I also tried GetR1(obj) { if (obj.checked = true){var labelText = document.getElementById("Label1").value or text
            alert(labelText)}  it returns {objectHTMLInputElement}

Comment: @CarlosSiles : do you want the radiobutton text or the asp:label text?

Comment: Avishek  and Naveen, THANK YOU VERY MUCH I FINALLY SOLVED THIS PROBLEM, YOUR SOLUTION HELPED ME A LOT. I WAS MAKING A MISTAKE while calling the src:jquery. The final solution for those who are looking for help is jquery code:  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">function GetR1(elm) {

   alert($(elm).next().html()); and the aspx code:  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="rdb" CliientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("type1") %>' onclick="GetR1(this);" />

Comment: IT WORKS, THANKS AGAIN GUYS, I WOULDN'T BE ABLE TO SOLVED THIS WITHOUT YOUR HEP.

Comment: Avishek,One more question: I can validate a checkbox when is checked but how would you validate it when is unchecked? I need to set extra='NO' this is my js code: function extra() {
     
         var elem=document.getElementById("Checkbox2");
         if (elem.checked = true) {
             extra = "YES";}}
         THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: @CarlosSiles : you can simply add a else part. `function extra() { var elem=document.getElementById("Checkbox2"); if (elem.checked = true) { extra = "YES";} else{extra = "NO";}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript.

```
function Getr1(elm) {
    var nextElm = elm.nextSibling;
    //catching white space, comments etc...
    while (nextElm && nextElm.nodeType != 1) {
        nextElm = nextElm.nextSibling
    }
    alert(nextElm.innerHTML);
}
```

Reason: asp:RadioButton is rendered like this in the browser

```
<input id="MainContent_RadioButton1" type="radio" onclick="Getr1(this);" 
     value="RadioButton1" name="ctl00$MainContent$rdb">
<label for="MainContent_RadioButton1">your rendered text here</label>
```

And if you use jQuery, it will be as simple as this.

```
function Getr1(elm) {
    alert( $(elm).next().html() );
}
```

Comment: Hello Navee, I tried onclientClick but still doesnt work, is any way to change  your javascript for an aspx radiobutton? thank you

Comment: i did not ask you to use `OnClientClick` just write put onclick in your asp:RadioButton like this `onclick="Getr1(this)"`

Comment: Naveen, one more question: I can validate a checkbox when is checked but how would you validate it when is unchecked? I need to set extra='NO' this is my js code: function extra() {
     
         var elem=document.getElementById("Checkbox2");
         if (elem.checked = true) {
             extra = "YES";}}
         THANKS IN ADVANCE